# Make [half-precision-float] and [fp16] whole?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

We have a recently created tag, [fp16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fp16), about half-precision (16 bit) floating-point numbers.

However, we already had a tag for half-precision floating-point numbers, namely [half-precision-float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/half-precision-float).

[half-precision-float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/half-precision-float) has been marked as a synonym of [precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/precision), though.

This makes it a bit awkward: we have two tags about the same subject, one is distinct, while the other is a synonym of another tag.

As far as I can see, we have three options:

1. Leave this situation be.
2. Mark [fp16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fp16) as a synonym of [precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/precision), so both tags do the same thing
3. Redirect the synonym for [half-precision-float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/half-precision-float) to [fp16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fp16), so both tags do the same thing

My personal opinion is we should go for option 3. Questions about 16 bit floating point numbers might not be specifically about precision, and imo an own tag is appropriate, but that probably goes against the reasoning why [half-precision-float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/half-precision-float) was marked as a synonym in the first place.

Can we discuss this?

Comment: Supporting option 3, since _half-precision_ almost always means 16-bit floating-point numbers.

Comment: option 2, it avoids vetting waves of variable type tags for inclusion. (i'm against 3 as it would block any other interpretation of half-precision, making it an architecture dependant tag)

Comment: These synonym/burninate post title puns just keep getting better and better.

Comment: Ugh. [half-precision-float] should have never been made a synonym of [precision]. They're not synonyms.

Comment: There's also the [double-precision] tag, which is a synonym of [precision] but (based on it having a tag wiki) appears to have been a standalone tag.  [half-precision-float] is the same thing but in the opposite direction. (I'm not saying I agree that these should all mean the same thing.) @CodyGray